# Cómo cerrar un JOptionPane.showMessaDialog con la tecla Enter

Tags: java, jtable

gracias por su tiempo en ayudarme con mi problema, estoy en Netbeans 8.2 y desde un jTable quiero hacer un update de las columnas 1 y 2 a una BD, pero al momento de enviar mensajes con JOptionPane (por ejemplo que el nombre en la celda 1 ya existe)y si presiono enter, el JOptionPane sigue mostrándose, forzosamente tengo que cerrarlo haciendo clic en él, esa sería una opción pero deseo que al darle la tecla enter al mensaje JOptioPane.showMessageDialog se cierre, gracias por sus comentarios

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
El código, las trazas de error y demás info debe ir en tu pregunta, siempre que se pueda, como texto. El código debería incluir detalle sobre esos otros componentes que mencionas y que idealmente no deberíamos tener que imaginar cómo son. Por favor edita tu pregunta.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: PD. Los detalles de lo que ves, cómo se ve, qué sale, qué no sale en pantalla, ahí sí sirve una captura de pantalla.

Comment: Coloca tu codigo, y no una imagen, asi podemos ayudarte mejor

Answer (score 0):

Lo que sucede es que el `KeyEvent` se ejecutara con cualquier tecla presionada por eso el enter ejecuta el método `tablasCategoriasKeyReleased` si solo quieres omitir esa tecla puedes agregar un filtro con un `if`:

```
private void tablasCategoriasKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
   // Ejecutamos el código solo si la tecla presionada no es enter
   if(!evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
   {
      // Codigo
   }
}
```